# Chrome dock icon looks blurry and low resolution

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I launch Chrome my icon never looks right and I can't open new windows by right clicking and selecting. I am also using Plank dock. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Idk if you guys can notice how the icon isn't HD, it's all blurry.

Comment: What launcher are you using?

Answer (score 3):

1. open a terminal and use `nano` to edit this file `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`
2. replace every instance of `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` to `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome`
3. reboot or logout and login again

As far as I can tell its a bug when they moved from GTK+ to Aura.