# Ubuntu 14.04 Google Chrome Broken

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome, icons

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Chrome seems to have broken with no way out.

I was fiddling with the command line flags, and I activated something that I did not want. I disabled it and restarted the browser, but then the following behavior commenced:

I would click on the "Google Chrome" icon in the Unity launcher, but even though it was there, another Chrome icon would pop up at the bottom of the launcher (the behavior of non-pinned running programs icons). Not only that, but the second icon would not have the proper right click menu, and also it's "name" (when hovering over the icon) is the tab that I had opened when things broke in the first place! Here's a screenshot illustrating this behavior:

[image: Why would it do this to me!?]

Look at the menu bar title and the icon title on the launcher, and note that there is already a chrome icon pinned.

How do I fix it? This is something that really bugs me and would even merit a reinstall.

I have already tried `apt-get purge`ing it, as well as deleting the `~/.config/google-chrome` folders. Nothing changed it.

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here. For me, it happened after looking at go documentation in the browser using something like `godoc -http=:6060` (I think)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome opens wrong](http://askubuntu.com/questions/396448/google-chrome-opens-wrong)

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report against google chrome. As it is third party application you will have to file with google. You can also try their forums - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/chrome

Comment: Does moving your chrome configuration help? (meaning that any settings you did set should be moved) - You can do this by running `mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome-backup`.

Comment: Hey man. I have also solved the problem with Steve W's answer. But have you been able to figure out the **reason** of this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I searched a little further and found [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396448/google-chrome-opens-wrong/413263#413263) topic and after following the instructions to remove the .Desktop file it has reset back to the original right-click menu.

Ubuntu 14.04 / Chrome-stable

Comment: The problem seems to be that there are two .desktop files for chrome, one in `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`, the other in `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome-stable.desktop`. Removing the latter fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, resolved problem with icon title. If you have similar problem with chromium, the file is `~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome dock icon looks blurry and low resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476578/chrome-dock-icon-looks-blurry-and-low-resolution/476996#476996?newreg=bfb7b24ddec0414a8da3cc808d268a33)

This answer may help you solve this problem,although it seems that it is an answer for another problem.
I have the same problem like you and this help me solve it.

Sorry, I didn't learn English well:(

Comment: I ended up switching to using the google-chrome-beta package so it works now, although I am now using the beta version of chrome :P

Comment: My problem appeared when I click restart buttom after I changed chrome flags.I don't know why...This both happened on elementary os and ubuntu official edition.

Comment: This worked for me, though the 'fake-entry' still remains in unity and can be found via dash search.